# How mapping @ManyToMany with primary key in extra table using java.util.List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

If i do this;

```
public class Client{

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(11)")
    private String cpf;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;
    //get set
}
```

.

```
public class Address{

    @Id
    private String zipCode;

    @Id
    private String number;

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'DONT HAVE'")
    private String complement;
    //get set
}
```

... I have this mapping:

[Image - Model using java.util.List with @ManyToMany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuA4R.png)

If i do this;

```
public class Client{

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(11)")
    private String cpf;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Address> addresses;
    //get set
}
```

.

```
public class Address{

    @Id
    private String zipCode;

    @Id
    private String number;

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'DONT HAVE'")
    private String complement;
    //get set
}
```

... I have this mapping:

[Image - Model using java.util.Set with @ManyToMany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Gvu.png)

The Question is:
**how do I get the attributes of the extra table automatically generated by @ManyToMany relationship are primary foreign keys(PFK) using java.util.List?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my jpa study, we don't need create a primary key in extra table generate by @ManyToMany.

This is my final solution:

```
public class Client{

   @Id
   @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(11)")
   private String cpf;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name="client_address", joinColumns = {
     @JoinColumn(name = "client_cpf") },
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_zipcode", 
       referencedColumnName="zipCode"), @JoinColumn(name = "address_number", 
         referencedColumnName="number", @JoinColumn(name = 
         "address_complement", 
         referencedColumnName="complement"},
     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
       "client_cpf", "address_zipcode", "address_number",  
       "address_complement" })
   private List<Address> addresses;
   //get set
}
```